# Codeigniter search + page number

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the pagination function in codeigniter, and I want to use a search function to search through the table + I want the searched word to be remembered when you go to another page. So it will go to page 2 of the new results with the searched word if I click on page 2.

How would I do this in the url?

For example this is my url

```
http://example.com/cars/blue/10
```

But it could also be this if search is left blank

```
http://example.com/cars/10
```

How would I handle this in the model or controller?

Comment: i think you want to have search with pagination if the result of the search is more using session to store the data searched and send the number of rows to session

Comment: how about store the search information in the session, and redirect to the corresponding url with the session?